# Stretch a left-aligned bar to trace multiple lines of text

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to build a list that's tracked by a sort of vertical progress bar on the left. Currently it looks ok on a 13" screen:

[image: Vertical bar intact]

But it's quite brittle. Text text for any item might end up running over multiple lines, and I might want to insert further text below any given item, and have the relevant segment of the bar on the left stretch vertically, so that we still end up with an unbroken bar. At the moment, it breaks like this:

[image: Vertical bar broken]

What would be the best way to achieve this affect in reasonably modern browsers?

The relevant parts of the current code are below, but I'm interested in best practice here, so don't feel obliged to read it (includes some minor ERB interpolation):

```
<li  class="deployment-step">
  <div class="increment-wrapper">
    <div class="progress-increment <%= #incomplete, progressing or complete %>">
      &nbsp
    </div>
    <%= #@line_text %>
  </div>
</li>

.my-deployments .deployment-steps .deployment-step {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.my-deployments .increment-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
.my-deployments .progress-increment {
  background-color: rgba(105,74,255,1);
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 2px;
}
.my-deployments .progress-increment.complete {
  border-left: 5px solid rgba(105,74,255,1);
  border-right: 5px solid rgba(105,74,255,1);
}
.my-deployments .final-step .progress-increment {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
}
.my-deployments .progress-increment.progressing {
  border-left: 5px solid rgba(105,74,255,0.2);
  border-right: 5px solid rgba(105,74,255,0.2);
  background-color: rgba(105,74,255,0.2);
  color: rgba(105,74,255,0.6);
}
.my-deployments .deployment-steps .incomplete {
  border-left: 4px solid #fafafe;
  border-right: 4px solid #fafafe;
  background-color: rgba(105,74,255,0.2);
  color: rgba(105,74,255,0.2);
  width: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve a much simpler and more versatile solution using borders:

https://jsfiddle.net/rjeLpbz7/2/

Also if you're building a responsive design, `px` units should be avoided. Usage of relative units like `em`, `rem`, `vw`, or `%` will make your design much more adaptable and accessible.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.deployment-step {
  list-style: none;
}

.deployment-step.incomplete {
  padding: .5em .5em .5em .8em;
  border-left: .15em rgba(105,74,255,0.2) solid;
  margin-left: .3em;
}

.deployment-step.progressing {
  border-left: .8em rgba(105,74,255,0.2) solid;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: .5em;
}

.deployment-step.complete {
  border-left: .8em rgba(105,74,255,1) solid;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="deployment-step complete">Step one</li>
  <li class="deployment-step progressing">Step two <br> more text</li>
  <li class="deployment-step incomplete">Step three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah, great solution, thanks! :) I tried playing with borders initially, but didn't think of this way of getting the shorter section centred like this.